# Changing the ASP.NET Culture based off of a dynamic value

Tags: asp.net, string, currency

I have a web application that tracks financial data.  I would like to have the option where a user can edit their currency via dropdown.  The different currency types will be held in a database and a user can then select which currency they wish to use.  The easiest way I can see doing this would be to check what the currency value is and dynamically change the culture to match the currency, thus I could continue to use the 
    `string str = String.Format("{0:C}", revenue);`
format.  I am open to other suggestions but this just seemed the most logical to me.  How can I handle this?

Comment: I think it's correct, you can use Page.InitializeCulture for this purpose. Or Global.asax hook up Page.PreInit and do it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the easiest way to do this is to create a base class that inherits the Page.  Then it is a simple override to the InitializeCulture() function.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this a couple of ways.

1. Pass in the intended culture as the first parameter of your `String.Format` calls, e.g.

   string str = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C}", revenue);
2. Change the default culture of the thread processing the request:

   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

The second option would need to be done at the beginning of each request, and would allow you to automatically use that culture with your formats and parsing, but you need to take care to ensure that any code that is processing a user response does so according to the default culture (which you'd be replacing).